# 「質問をみる」の2ページ目を表示する方法がありますか。

Tags: サポート

トップページの「質問をみる」 ( https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ ) を表示後、
「質問をもっと見る」をクリックすると、
「すべての質問」 ( https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions ) に切り替わります。
様式が変わらないよう,「質問をみる」の2ページ目を表示する方法がありますか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「様式」というのは、質問のタイトルのみが列挙されているような、デザインの問題ですか？　それとも「アクティブ」「人気」「今週」「今月」のような、ソート順の問題でしょうか。

Comment: デザインの問題です。表示の行数が増えます。

Answer (score 2):

私の知る限り、トップページのデザインのままで2ページ目を表示する標準の方法はありません。

(もちろん、https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active を表示する際にデザインを変更するようなブラウザ拡張を作れば可能だと思いますが……)

Comment: あるいは「サポート」ではなく「機能の要求」とすることは可能だと思います。